# Saving an image extracted using PdfPig

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, console-application

I am experimenting with PdfPig in a Console App (.Net Core) project using C#.

The following code intends to get images from a PDF and save them to my desktop:

```
IEnumerable<IPdfImage> images = page.GetImages();

foreach (IPdfImage image in images)
{
    Console.WriteLine(image);
    byte[] bitmap = image.RawBytes.ToArray();
    string exportPath = @"C:\Users\ed\Desktop\" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg";   
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(exportPath, bitmap);
}
```

From the console output I can see that two images are extracted from the PDF I am testing:

```
XObject Image (w 595.1999999999999, h 841.92): <Type, /XObject>, <Subtype, /Image>, <Width, 2480>, <Height, 3508>, <BitsPerComponent, 1>, <ColorSpace, /DeviceGray>, <Filter, /CCITTFaxDecode>, <DecodeParms, <Columns, 2480>, <Rows, 3508>>, <Length, 381787>

XObject Image (w 595.1999999999999, h 841.92): <Type, /XObject>, <Subtype, /Image>, <Width, 2480>, <Height, 3508>, <BitsPerComponent, 1>, <ColorSpace, /DeviceGray>, <Filter, /CCITTFaxDecode>, <DecodeParms, <Columns, 2480>, <Rows, 3508>>, <Length, 241054>
```

Two .jpg files are also created on my desktop; however, when I open the file it appears there is something wrong with the output. For example, I get the error message:

```
97266a2b-5e2b-49e1-8b19-f6716f294a4d.jpg it appears that we don't support this file format.
```

Please may someone suggest how to amend this; I suspect there is an issue with how I am creating the image files.

Thank you!

Comment: You assume the raw bytes of a pdf image to constitute a jpg image. That need not be the case, pdf has a number of bitmap formats.

Comment: That checks out. Are you aware of a way that I could identify and export the correct file format?

Comment: it looks like the images are tif file fromat i took this from your question "CCITTFaxDecode".

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
IReadOnlyList<byte> bytes = Array.Empty<byte>();
if (imageItem.TryGetBytes(out bytes))
{
    bytes = imageItem.RawBytes;
}
using var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes.ToArray());
using var image = SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Load(stream, out IImageFormat format);
image.SaveAsJpeg(pathToFileJpeg);
```